# JQuery If Statement Returns same number regardless of the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really easy HTML form and some JQuery to calculate a figure.

The issue I have is that the if statement returns the same number irrelevant of the input:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('input').change(function()
        {
            var behind = escape($('#behind').val());
            var speed = parseInt($('#speed').val());
            var diff;

if (behind = "nse") { diff = '0.83'; }
if (behind = "0.5") { diff = '1.66'; }
if (behind = "0.75") { diff = '2.49'; }

var hsr = speed-diff;
$('#hsr').html(hsr);

        });
    });
```

If I input nse into the box the calculation uses diff = '2.49' instead of diff = '0.83' as I've programmed.

The jsFiddle page with the full code is at http://jsfiddle.net/Jucna/1/

Please could someone explain what is wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comparison operator `==` instead of assignment operator `=` in if statement.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jucna/4/)**

```
if (behind == "nse") { diff = '0.83'; }
if (behind == "0.5") { diff = '1.66'; }
if (behind == "0.75") { diff = '2.49'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> == compare
>
> = assign

```
if (behind == "nse")
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing a `=` in your if statements

```
if (behind == "nse") { diff = '0.83'; }
if (behind == "0.5") { diff = '1.66'; }
if (behind == "0.75") { diff = '2.49'; }
```

Using one `=` assigns a value rather than comparing it.